# Google Events API: Total Count of Events in a Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need the total count of events in a google calendar. The v3 events API doesn't seem to offer this. 
Anything obvious I'm missing? Or just not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to retrieve all events associated with a calendar. Give it a quick run in the Try-it.

There are also [sample Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) which show how to list these events.

Comment: as many of users really have a lot of events in their calendars, this is not really an option